# Resizing the Ubuntu partition to release space to install Fedora to dual boot

Tags: resize, boot-partition

I have purchased Dell Vostro 3400 laptop computer that came with Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS preinstalled on a 1TB HDD. (it has enough free space)

Output of fdisk p command in given below:

```
dell@dell-Vostro-3400:~$ sudo fdisk /dev/sda
```

```
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.34).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sda: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: ST1000LM035-1RK1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 78F0AD73-AA07-4A06-B90A-5461E161464E

Device        Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1      2048    1794047    1792000   875M EFI System
/dev/sda2   1794048   18571263   16777216     8G Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3  18571264 1953523711 1934952448 922.7G Linux filesystem
```

Ubuntu is installed and running from /dev/sda3. I want to resize /dev/sda3 and release some space so that I can install Fedora Workstation (and dual boot Ubuntu and Fedora) without losing the Ubuntu installation that came with the computer when I purchased it (as I believe it has all the appropriate device drivers, etc. and I do not want to lose them.)

What is the best way I can dual-boot this computer with Ubuntu (it came with Ubuntu) and Fedora (which I want to install) without losing the existing Ubuntu installation? (As this is a fresh machine I do not have any data here.)

When I tried to use Disks utility to resize the Ubuntu partition it says

```
Error unmounting filesystem 

Error unmounting /dev/sda3: target is busy (udisks-error-quarks, 14)
```

Comment: Backup all data (*it's easy to make a mistake & lose everything when making partition changes*) and either install Fedora (Ubuntu provides many ISOs & installers, most have an *Install Alongside* option) or resize your partitions then install. You can't resize many file-systems when they are in use, so using *live* media is the easiest way around this.

Comment: You can resize the partition with GParted from the Fedora live USB.